# Is there a place where I can ask question about Electronic appliances?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a place on Stack Exchange where I can ask about or discuss electronic appliances like Air conditioners, Mobiles, etc.?

Comment: I fear that no such site exists, at first I was about to suggest http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ but quick look in their [about page](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/about) clearly says "Don't ask about *Consumer electronics such as media players, cell phones or smart phones, except when designing these products or modifying their electronics for other uses*"

Answer (score 3):

If by "mobiles" you mean phones, we have [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/), [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/), and even [Windows Phone](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/). Nothing for 'berry though, sorry.

For air conditioners you could look at [Home Improvement](http://diy.stackexchange.com)

Comment: HEy AakashM, thanks a lot, can i ask question like which AC to buy, which is good? something like that?

Comment: No, shopping questions are off-topic on every SE site, because they aren't a good fit for the SE model. Sorry.